# What about duplicate questions if duplicate was deleted in the meantime?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I just had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782892/python-functions-procedures) which was closed since it was marked as duplicate.

However, the original question the marked duplicate refers to was deleted in the meantime. How should such cases be handled since the question is not a duplicate anymore?

Comment: You know what the difference between the posts is? Someone formatted the code in one, while the other was deleted (RemovedAbandonedClosed). Both posts aren'worth anything though.

Comment: Usually it shouldn't happen that referenced duplicates are deleted.